# vps ubuntu server enable mysql

Tags: mysql, vps, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to enable mysql on vps ubuntu server(Joomla installation stops on database page I'm getting

`Error
Could not connect to the database. Connector returned number: Could not connect to MySQL.).`

I assume that is because I couldn't enable mysql

`sudo systemctl enable mysql
mysql.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mysql`

How can I fix it?
There was no issue on localhost.

Comment: This question would probably get a better response on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I till try Dave, thx.